# creating a Binary tree based on a prefix expression

Tags: trees, binary

I want to find the value of a the prefix expression `-/+8,10,2*3,2` and build its binary tree I am trying to learn this for a math course, but have absolutely no clue how to do it. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Think of a binary operator as a function whose two inputs are the next two numbers that come directly to the right of it. That is, if we define the following functions:
\begin{align*}
s(x,y) &= x-y \\
d(x,y) &= x/y \\
a(x,y) &= x+y \\
m(x,y) &= x*y \\
\end{align*}

then you can interpret the prefix expression to be:

$$
s\left(d \left( a \left(8, 10 \right), 2\right),  m\left(3 , 2 \right) \right)
$$

Comment: just confirming answer is 3?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can even Try using stack to solve it which is much more easy than the binary tree. 
In-fact the expression tree is just other form of representation However OS internally invokes stack to compute the result on the real machine..
For you i have mentioned both .
Please feel free to ask if you get any more doubt and/or any other doubt in Data structures or related field.

And Yes the **Answer** is 3.

[image: https://www.facebook.com/bewithjitendrapatel]